# vimperator copying and pasting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, vimperator

I can't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to copy and paste respectively.

I know that if I want to do so in Firefox vimperator I'll have to add these lines:

```
noremap <C-c> <C-v><C-c>
noremap <C-v> <C-v><C-v>
```

However, I'm not sure exactly what the file is or where I can find it to place that code in.

Answer (score 2):

Vimperator uses Ctrl-V to tell it to pass the next command straight to Firefox. If you go `Ctrl-V Ctrl-C` that copies, and `Ctrl-V Ctrl-V` will paste. However, you may be better off remapping if you don't need Ctrl-V passthrough for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

vimperator reads file `~/.vimperatorrc` during startup. Create/modify that file at will.

Comment: i don't have such aaa file. i have a .vimperator folder. is this due to an updated version?

Comment: Did you try to create that file as I suggested? :-) Don't know, but the current vimperator manual still states that vimperator reads ~/.vimperatorrc during startup. Try and see, it won't hurt you!

Answer (score 0):

`:mkvimperatorrc` will create the initial ~/.vimperatorrc file, then you can manually add anything to it.

`:source ~/.vimperatorrc` allows you to re-read it, without restarting Firefox (`:restart`).

You might want to use the X clipboard instead (via <kbd>Shift-Insert</kbd> (Paste) and <kbd>Shift-Delete</kbd> (Cut)).

Also, Y will yank any selected text the vimperator way (both to clipboard and X11 selection).

You might be interested in my vimperatorrc: http://github.com/blueyed/dotfiles/blob/master/vimperatorrc

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, but I have no idea why as I don't understand the difference between no, cno, and ino remap

```
" mswin.vimp - mappings to make copy/paste in Vimperator behave like Windows
" Maintainer: Doug Kearns <dougkearns@gmail.com>
" Last Change: 31 Oct 2008

noremap <C-q> <C-v>
noremap <C-Q> <C-z>
" TODO: this should probably be <C-Break> - see :help dos-CTRL-break in Vim
noremap <C-s> <C-c>

inoremap <C-q> <C-v>
inoremap <C-Q> <C-z>
inoremap <C-s> <C-c>

noremap <C-a> <C-v><C-a>
noremap <C-c> <C-v><C-c>
noremap <C-v> <C-v><C-v>
noremap <C-x> <C-v><C-x>
noremap <C-z> <C-v><C-z>
noremap <C-y> <C-v><C-y>

cnoremap <C-a> <C-v><C-a>
cnoremap <C-c> <C-v><C-c>
cnoremap <C-v> <C-v><C-v>
cnoremap <S-Insert> <C-v><C-v>
cnoremap <C-x> <C-v><C-x>
cnoremap <C-z> <C-v><C-z>
cnoremap <C-y> <C-v><C-y>

inoremap <C-a> <C-v><C-a>
inoremap <C-c> <C-v><C-c>
inoremap <C-v> <C-v><C-v>
inoremap <S-Insert> <C-v><C-v>
inoremap <C-x> <C-v><C-x>
inoremap <C-z> <C-v><C-z>
inoremap <C-y> <C-v><C-y>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been bothered by the problem for so long time even I dont recall when It started.

my final solution is

```
inoremap <C-v> <C-v>
```

and it works great!

once when I  It paste twice! That is very annoying!

I tried

```
inoremap <C-v> <C-v><C-v>
```

that seems like make sense, but It's useless cause It doesnt' work!

In the process of fixing this , I tried `inoremap <C-v> i<C-v><esc>`, this makes difference. after some tries, it came down to that final solution.